# How do I get LAN speeds on device with different public ip?

Tags: networking, wired-networking

I want to setup my network with the following configuration. A switch going out of my router which would provide a public ip to a server and a public ip to my home network. How do I configure my network such that a device communicating with the server has a connection with local network speeds?

Comment: So, how are you getting 2 different public IPs from one incoming connection? Do you have a block of public IPs? Is this enterprise? Is the switch managed or unmanaged? Could always use 2 nics, with the second cards being on the same private subnet.

Comment: @Narzard I am just connecting my modem to a managed switch which assigns my router a public ip and my server a managed ip. This is not enterprise (just a homelab). Since the server has a multiport network card could I connect one port to the switch to get a public ip and another port to my router to acess to my private network?

Answer (score 0):

This will "just work" provided your router CPU can process the packets quickly enough, but I fear you are asking the wrong question.

Although not what you asked, the information below explains how it all fits together and is likely what you need to understand to interpret my short answer above.

In order to do what you propose, you will need to get IP space from your ISP. This typically means **you will need to get a subnet if world routable IPs routed over your Internet connection from them** Typically the minimum allocation  to do this would need to he a /29 (8 real IPs - its a wasteful process).  Your ISP should advise you of the range and netmask (which will be something like 255.255.255.248). You then assign one of these IPs to your router, and 2 others to your server and computer - You can't use the first or last IP in the range, and the gateway address on the computers need to be the router WITH THE NETMASK SET.

**The Netmask is what identifies the computer and router as one group, and allows computers to talk to each other directly at the speed between them, without needing to be routed by the router**  - I note I said routed. If you use a regular switch the packets will not go through the router, but if the devices are plugged into the LAN port of the router they need to go through the onboard "switch". Unfortunately this is usually not a real switch but one created in Software, which means if the router CPU is not fast enough it can bottleneck the direct communication between the systems. [Yes, you can just add a cheap gigabit switch between the computers and router LAN port] to bypass the bottleneck.

Comment: Of my answer is not what you are looking for, can you explain the thinking that prompted your question and someone - maybe myself - can address that.